# Maps marker point image with picasso not loaded at first time

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm implementing android Mapview with Custom marker. I'm using picasso to load image into marker view. And when i launch the app at the first time, it shows me all the markers, but only one marker that has loaded from database with picasso, the other markers are not loaded from database, they only show me the default maps marker pin. But when i go to the previous activity and go back into MapsActivity, it shows me all the markers that loaded from database with picasso.

Here's my PicassoMarker class

```
public class PicassoMarker implements Target {
Marker mMarker;

    PicassoMarker(Marker marker) {
        mMarker = marker;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return mMarker.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if(o instanceof PicassoMarker) {
            Marker marker = ((PicassoMarker) o).mMarker;
            return mMarker.equals(marker);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        mMarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
        //mMarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.here));
    }
}
```

Here's the method in MapsActivity

```
public void plotMarkers(ArrayList<MyMarker> markers) {
    if(markers.size() > 0) {
        for (MyMarker myMarker : markers)
        {
            markerOption = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(myMarker.getmLatitude(), myMarker.getmLongitude()));
            location_marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOption);
            target = new PicassoMarker(location_marker);
            Picasso.with(MapsActivity.this).load(myMarker.getmIcon()).resize(84, 125).into(target);
            mMarkersHashMap.put(location_marker, myMarker);

            i = getIntent();
            if(i.getBooleanExtra("maps", true)) {
                buttonNavigasi.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                location_marker.setTitle(i.getStringExtra("nama"));
                dest = new LatLng(myMarker.getmLatitude(), myMarker.getmLongitude());
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(dest, 16));
            }
            else {
                mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MarkerInfoWindowAdapter());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What's going wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about this since I cannot test it on my end, but have you tried calling these lines `target = new PicassoMarker(location_marker);    Picasso.with(MapsActivity.this).load(myMarker.getmIcon()).resize(84, 125).into(target);` before `location_marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOption);` ?

Comment: Can you try it out and tell me if it somehow works..?

Comment: Yeah, i have tried it, but i get the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so I managed to reproduce what you are experiencing and found what was causing your problem. In the code you provided, notice this line in `MapsActivity`:

```
target = new PicassoMarker(location_marker);
```

I presumed that you are using a global single variable for `target`. I added some logs and managed to see that the only Marker that gets the image loaded using `Picasso` is the **last** `Marker` in the for loop.

The reason is because, every time you enter the loop, the value of `target` changes to the **newer** `PicassoMarker` that you have, making the `onBitmapLoaded` of the **previous** `PicassoMarker` you have **useless**, since it no longer has a target. :(

So what I did is, I just added a `List<Target>` variable (*make sure you don't forget to initialize it*) to store the instances of the `target`s.  In the line where that I specified earlier, I just added the code to store the value of the `target` to the list, like so:

```
Target target = new PicassoMarker(location_marker);
targets.add(target);
```

Tested it on my emulator and it loads the images to all the `Marker`s.

> EDIT

Here is the Activity code I used to reproduce your error and then modified it to make it work:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    Intent i;
    MarkerOptions markerOption;
    List<Target> targets;
    HashMap<Marker, MyMarker> mMarkersHashMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        mMarkersHashMap = new HashMap<>();
        targets = new ArrayList<>();

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        // LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        // mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        // mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
        ArrayList<MyMarker> markers = new ArrayList<MyMarker>();
        MyMarker m1 = new MyMarker(new LatLng(-34, 151.1), "https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/idle/idle_simple/sample-128.png");
        MyMarker m2 = new MyMarker(new LatLng(-34, 151.2), "https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/idle/idle_simple/sample-128.png");
        MyMarker m3 = new MyMarker(new LatLng(-34, 151.3), "https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/idle/idle_simple/sample-128.png");

        markers.add(m1);
        markers.add(m2);
        markers.add(m3);

        plotMarkers(markers);

        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                Log.d(MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "MARKER Longitude: " + marker.getPosition().longitude);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    public void plotMarkers(ArrayList<MyMarker> markers) {
        if (markers.size() > 0) {
            for (MyMarker myMarker : markers) {

                markerOption = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(myMarker.getmLatitude(), myMarker.getmLongitude()));
                Marker location_marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOption);

                Target target = new PicassoMarker(location_marker);
                targets.add(target);
                Picasso.with(MapsActivity.this).load(myMarker.getmIcon()).resize(84, 125).into(target);

                mMarkersHashMap.put(location_marker, myMarker);

                i = getIntent();
                if (i.getBooleanExtra("maps", true)) {
                    // buttonNavigasi.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    location_marker.setTitle(i.getStringExtra("nama"));
                    LatLng dest = new LatLng(myMarker.getmLatitude(), myMarker.getmLongitude());
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(dest, 8f));
                } else {
                    Log.d(MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "In else{}");
                    // mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MarkerInfoWindowAdapter());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, only Marker that gets the image loaded using Picasso is the last Marker in the for loop. I have tried to add a variable like this `private List<Target> targets;`

Comment: Did you also just instantiate the target inside the loop? `Target target = ....` and not using a single global variable?

Comment: and i have change my code like this
`markerOption = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(myMarker.getmLatitude(), myMarker.getmLongitude()));
                location_marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOption);
                Target target = new PicassoMarker(location_marker);
                targets.add(target);
                Picasso.with(MapsActivity.this).load(myMarker.getmIcon()).resize(84, 125).into(target);
                mMarkersHashMap.put(location_marker, myMarker);` but the app is crash. Can you show me the correct full code? Thanks in advance

Comment: Added my code for the activity.. I didn't change anything in the `PicassoMarker`

Comment: Should i use this variable `private PicassoMarker target;` ?

Comment: Oops, sorry i forget to initialize it in `onCreate()` . It works fine now, thank u very much. But i have problem when `if(i.getBooleanExtra("maps", true))` . It not shows me a marker. What's wrong?

Comment: This is my code in onCreate()


`i = getIntent();
        if(i.getBooleanExtra("maps", true)) {
            mactionBar.setSubtitle(i.getStringExtra("nama"));
            mMyMarkersArray.add(new MyMarker(i.getStringExtra("nama"), i.getStringExtra("deskripsi"), i.getStringExtra("foto"), i.getStringExtra("marker"), Double.parseDouble(i.getStringExtra("lat")), Double.parseDouble(i.getStringExtra("lng"))));
            plotMarkers(mMyMarkersArray);
        }`

The app is crash when get `getBooleanExtra("maps", true)`

Comment: If the answer I posted answers the original post, that's pretty much it. What your thinking is a different concern already. Try to post it as a question, along with the details. Pretty sure a lot of people from the community would like to help you with your concern. I'll take a look at it too if I have the time. ;)

Comment: Thanks, please take a look to my new qustion on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36134197/custom-maps-marker-point-with-picasso-not-loaded