# Custom maps marker point with picasso not loaded

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, picasso

I'm implementing android Mapview with Custom marker. I'm using picasso to load image into marker view. But the maps not shows me the marker that i needed.

Here's my code

```
i = getIntent();
    if(i.getBooleanExtra("maps", true)) {
        mactionBar.setSubtitle(i.getStringExtra("nama"));
        mMyMarkersArray.add(new MyMarker(i.getStringExtra("nama"), i.getStringExtra("deskripsi"), i.getStringExtra("foto"), i.getStringExtra("marker"), Double.parseDouble(i.getStringExtra("lat")), Double.parseDouble(i.getStringExtra("lng"))));
        plotMarkers(mMyMarkersArray);
    }
```

Here the code to load image marker. I'm implementing `if(i.getBooleanExtra("maps", true))` because there are two activities that lead to this mapsview. If the previous activity put a true value, then it will bring just one marker data. But if the value is false, it will bring all markers data. The mapsview shows me all the markers that i needed if it got from the previous activity that bring false value. But the mapsview not shows me a marker if it got from the activity that bring the true value.

```
public void plotMarkers(ArrayList<MyMarker> markers) {
    if(markers.size() > 0) {
        for (MyMarker myMarker : markers)
        {
            markerOption = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(myMarker.getmLatitude(), myMarker.getmLongitude()));
            location_marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOption);
            Target target = new PicassoMarker(location_marker);
            targets.add(target);
            Picasso.with(MapsActivity.this).load(myMarker.getmIcon()).resize(84, 125).into(target);
            mMarkersHashMap.put(location_marker, myMarker);

            i = getIntent();
            if(i.getBooleanExtra("maps", true)) {
                buttonNavigasi.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                location_marker.setTitle(i.getStringExtra("nama"));
                dest = new LatLng(myMarker.getmLatitude(), myMarker.getmLongitude());
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(dest, 16));
            }
            else {
                mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MarkerInfoWindowAdapter());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the the code on how i call the MapsActivity

```
buttonNavigasi = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    buttonNavigasi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(DetailActivity.this,MapsActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("nama", daftarNama);
            i.putExtra("deskripsi", daftarDeskripsi);
            i.putExtra("foto", daftarFoto);
            i.putExtra("marker", daftarMarker);
            i.putExtra("lng", daftarLng);
            i.putExtra("lat", daftarLat);
            i.putExtra("maps", true);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Here's the method of plotMarkers

```
public void plotMarkers(ArrayList<MyMarker> markers) {
    if(markers.size() > 0) {
        for (MyMarker myMarker : markers)
        {
            markerOption = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(myMarker.getmLatitude(), myMarker.getmLongitude()));
            location_marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOption);
            Target target = new PicassoMarker(location_marker);
            targets.add(target);
            Picasso.with(MapsActivity.this).load(myMarker.getmIcon()).resize(84, 125).into(target);
            mMarkersHashMap.put(location_marker, myMarker);

            i = getIntent();
            if(i.getBooleanExtra("maps", true)) {
                buttonNavigasi.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                location_marker.setTitle(i.getStringExtra("nama"));
                dest = new LatLng(myMarker.getmLatitude(), myMarker.getmLongitude());
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(dest, 16));
            }
            else {
                mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MarkerInfoWindowAdapter());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PicassoMarker class

```
public class PicassoMarker implements Target {
Marker mMarker;

    PicassoMarker(Marker marker) {
        mMarker = marker;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return mMarker.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if(o instanceof PicassoMarker) {
            Marker marker = ((PicassoMarker) o).mMarker;
            return mMarker.equals(marker);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
       mMarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
    }
}
```

What's wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: I've seen this if condition in your previous post: `if(i.getBooleanExtra("maps", true))` and I'm still not sure what is it's purpose? Can you include in your post why you're checking that value?

Comment: Check my post again.

Comment: Can you include the code snippet on how you call the `MapsActivity`? Also, where are you calling the `if(i.getBooleanExtra("maps", true))`? In the `onCreate()` I hope..

Comment: Check my post again. Yeah, i'm calling `if(i.getBooleanExtra("maps", true))` in the `onCreate()`

Comment: Have you also tried using `Log` to see if you are actually receiving `true` in the `MapsActivity`? Like so `Log.d(MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "Intent.maps=" + i.getBooleanExtra("maps", true));`?  Maybe the reason it is not going through is because the value you're receiving is actually `false`.

Comment: I can't see the log, because my usb hardware is not function properly. And my laptop will lag if i run it through emulator. So, i run the app through the installation of the apk in my android device. But if i added the code like this `Handler UI_HANDLER = new Handler();
        UI_HANDLER.postDelayed(UI_UPDATE_RUNNABLE, 2000);` in `onCreate()` and this code `Runnable UI_UPDATE_RUNNABLE = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            plotMarkers(mMyMarkersArray);
        }
    };` the app will shows me a marker that i needed but it has delay. What should i do?

Comment: @sept Can you give me the solution of my question? How can i show the marker icon without using `Handler` to show the marker that i needed without delay time? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you done what I mentioned in my previous comment? Adding logs in your code, to see the data flow? If you're actually getting a true value? and if the code is actually going inside the loop (`plotMarkers`)

Comment: Are you absolutely positive that the marker isn't added to the map? Or is it just that the map is not moving towards the marker? :)

Comment: The map camera is moving towards the marker, but the marker isn't shown :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107081/discussion-between-sept-and-michael-julyus-christopher-m).

Comment: If you were able to solve your own question, kindly post the answer so that other user will be able to see it. You might help someone with it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Handler to show the markers with some delay. So i change my code like this

```
i = getIntent();
if(i.getBooleanExtra("maps", true)) {
    ActionBar mactionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    mactionBar.setSubtitle(i.getStringExtra("nama"));
    buttonNavigasi.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mMyMarkersArray.add(new MyMarker(i.getStringExtra("nama"), i.getStringExtra("deskripsi"), i.getStringExtra("foto"), i.getStringExtra("marker"), Double.parseDouble(i.getStringExtra("lat")), Double.parseDouble(i.getStringExtra("lng"))));

    Handler UI_HANDLER = new Handler();
    UI_HANDLER.postDelayed(UI_UPDATE_RUNNABLE, 500);
}
```

And this

```
Runnable UI_UPDATE_RUNNABLE = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        plotMarkers(mMyMarkersArray);
    }
};
```